# How to change theme in GTK4.0 on windows?

Tags: gtk4, gtkmm4

I'm new to development using GTK. I installed gtkmm4.0 on windows using mingw64, but i noticed that the applications generated follow the default theme(adwaita); however i want to change that and use the windows 10 native theme. Where is the *settings.ini* file located in windows 10? I have searched it in the usual places described on the web, but could not find it(even tried creating one myself),does GTK4.0 on windows have a *settings.ini* file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in any of (but you will probably need to create it yourself):

```
DLL prefix/share/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
DLL prefix/etc/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
C:/Documents and Settings/username/Local Settings/Application Data/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
```

You can also use the `GTK_THEME` environment variable.

Note that GTK no longer ships a default Windows imitation theme in GTK4 (in GTK3 it was really, really, really, bad anyway).
If you want to have a native Windows look, you will need to write your own theme.

Also, in recent versions of GTK, the default theme is not "Adwaita", but "Default"

Comment: There are no `user/local settings/application data` or `user/application data` directories under Windows as far as I know. What kind of Windows are you using?